# Can I rely on a CDN to permanently store photos?

Tags: amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I'm working on a photo heavy site and don't have a lot of storage available at my hosting location.

If I use a CDN like CloudFront can I rely on them to permanently store the photos so I can delete them from my servers?
Or should I first transfer them to a service like S3 for long term storage and then have the CDN pull from that location?

Are there any options?

Comment: Hard drives are pretty cheap now-a-days. Maybe back them up locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally never trust a CDN as a permanent data storage mechanism.  The odds of a random purge happening for reasons beyond your control are very high.

Using something like S3 sounds like a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

CDN is not storage, it is more likely a cache -- you can not persist your data on a cache.